# Total for stacked area chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

On a stacked area graph, is there any way to display what the total of all the series are for the last data point other than eyeballing that it looks somewhere around 115 in the example below?

[image]

I know I can add data labels for the individual data series, but some initial googling / experimenting isn't turning up any way to show the total...

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Add a data series for the total above the individual areas
2. Change fill of "total" series to "no fill"
3. Add Data Lables to "total" series
4. Delete all lables except for the last one

Only problem: The data lable will be too high. This can be changed manually, but not automatically like with the stacked bar chart, where you can select "Inside Base" for the lable position

Comment: According to Bela's reply, I would suggest right click the chart > Change Chart Type > Check the box of "Secondary of Axis" for "total" series. In my opinion, it may avoid compressing the original chart.

Comment: Bela made a good first step. Emily a good second step. Now, if you change chart type to line and don't change to secondary axis, then format the line series to use no markers and no lines, it will line up fine with the total of the area series without any unneeded display elements, except for the data label you'll add.